# How to clear all object on NSView in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I want to clear all objects which added to NSVIew before call any function.
How can I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you creating the view programmatically or loading from a Nib/xib

Comment: I create it programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following function

```
-(void)clearAllSubviewsOfView :(NSView *)parent
{
    for (NSView *subview in [parent subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Look's like it should be `[parent subviews]`

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

//  TSClearSupporting.h

```
@protocol TSClearSupporting <NSObject>
- (void) clear;
@end
```

//  TSTextField.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TSClearSupporting.h"

@interface TSTextField : NSTextField <TSClearSupporting>
@end
```

//  TSTextField.m

```
#import "TSTextField.h"

@implementation TSTextField
- (void) clear
{
    self.stringValue = @"";
}
@end
```

//  TSMainView.m

```
#import "TSMainView.h"
#import "TSClearSupporting.h"

@implementation TSMainView

- (IBAction) clearAll: (id)sender
{
    NSArray* subViews = self.subviews;

    for (NSView* view in subViews)
    {
        if ([view conformsToProtocol: @protocol(TSClearSupporting)])
        {
            [view performSelector: @selector(clear)];
        }
    }
}
```